# Firebase serve fails but deploy works fine

Tags: node.js, linux, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am following a [tutorial on cloud functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=2). This function accesses a Firestore database. Anyway, I am able to deploy and test. But if i try to do it locally through `firebase serve --only functions` it says

> An unexpected error has occurred.

when I try with `sudo firebase serve --only functions` it says

> Command requires authentication, please run firebase login

When I run `firebase login` it says

> Already logged in as

I look at my firebase.json and it looks like this

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Of course I ran lint and build before all of this.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [Cloud Functions Node.js Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator). it works much better, I think.